# Can I use next-intl using translates from a database? I mean, having user info (es, en) in firebase

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, next-intl

I am starting a new project on Next Js, also using the new Next 13 with the app folder routing. I am starting with the package next-intl, https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started.

I see all messages are stored in the JSON files, also I want to include some features where people can store some information (for example the BIO) and they can use it in 2 languages.

Don't know if there is some out-the-box feature or have to make it manually.

At the same time, there is other information from the website (prices and features) that want to keep on the database, but have the possibility to get it 2 languages.

Currently have the project and some info already on Firebase. I have integrated the https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started library but no more. Read the docs and no info about it